# how to stay in the webview with intel-sdk crosswalk?

Tags: intel-xdk

I have below code to open a new browser window which is external URL other than the my applcation

```
<button id="button" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';">click</button>
```

Problem is: How can I stay within the browser when I open an http url ?

I crosswalk version10, -latest intel-xdk -

function onDeviceReady() {

```
        if( navigator.splashscreen && navigator.splashscreen.hide ) {   // Cordova hide splashscreen detected, use it
            navigator.splashscreen.hide() ;
            alert("Device is ready !");
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
            alert("Started");

        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false) ;    // ignored by "Standard HTML5 web app"
</script>
```

I have the first alert "Device is ready");
but it never navigates to apache.org and I never got the second alert !

I added in App Browser (0.5.4) into Cordova included plugins.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is best to use the [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin when trying to open URLs within a Cordova app (you are building Cordova apps with the Intel XDK). There are several open options associated with that plugin and it will give you the control you need.

Comment: so I need to use: crosswalk + inAppBrowser ?

Comment: <script id="xdkJSonDeviceReady_">
        function onDeviceReady() {
            
            if( navigator.splashscreen && navigator.splashscreen.hide ) {   // Cordova hide splashscreen detected, use it
                navigator.splashscreen.hide() ;
                alert("Device is ready !");
                var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
                alert("Started");
                
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false) ;    // ignored by "Standard HTML5 web app"
    </script>

Comment: Crosswalk is an alternate WebView, Cordova provides unique and useful extensions to the WebView, whether you're talking about Crosswalk or the native WebView. See http://blogs.intel.com/evangelists/2014/09/02/html5-web-app-webview-app/ for some background on what a WebView is.

Comment: BTW: here are the official docs for the inAppBrowser plugin > https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser